# 'includes' search behavior on SOSL

Tags: sosl, search, include

Reading about 'includes' filter on SOSL I have a question:

What happens if I do: `...MyCustomField__c includes ('valueA,valueB')` ?

**What i know:**.
If I do: `...MyCustomField__c includes ('valueA;valueB')` it will return results with valueA ***OR*** valueB.
If I do: `...MyCustomField__c includes ('valueA','valueB')` it will return results with valueA ***AND*** valueB

Moreover for: `...MyCustomField__c includes ('valueA,valueB')` is not clear for me what happens...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm#topic-title

Comment: The doc you're referencing is for searching the multi-select picklist field values. Is your field a multi-select picklist?

Comment: Yes, it's a multi-select picklist

Comment: And have you actually tried that on any example? What were the results?

Comment: Sorry, but why are you not trying?

Comment: Yes I did but I have random results. I could not find the pattern, that's why I am asking.

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Please edit your question and show these "random" results along with the dataset you're searching. Take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and have a look at the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).